# Finding a basis for the span of 5 vectors in $R^4$

Tags: linear-algebra

Finding a basis for the span of 5 vectors in $R^4$.

I put the vectors as column vectors into a 4x6 augmented matrix with the last column being all zeros. When I solve for $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5$, I get $x_1=0, x_2=x_4-3x_5, x_3=-x_4+x_5$.

1. Does this mean that the first three vectors form my basis?
2. What do the last two expressions (of $x_2, x_3$) mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means you found all possible coefficients $x_1,\dots, x_5$ that make $x_1v_1+\dots+x_nv_n=0$.

That is, for any numbers $x_4,x_5$ there is a unique choice of $x_1,x_2$ and $x_3$ for the above. In particular, choosing $x_4=1,\ x_5=0$ we see that $v_4$ can be expressed by $v_2,v_3$, and similarly, with $x_4=0,\ x_5=1$ also $v_5$ can be expressed by $v_2, v_3$, so we can conclude that $v_1,v_2, v_3$ generates the span of $v_1,\dots,v_5$.

To show they are also linearly independent, we can finish e.g. by the dimension theorem for the map $(x_1,\dots, x_5)^T \mapsto (v_1,\dots, v_5)(x_1,\dots, x_5)^T$.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't understand "To show they are also …," but I know that $x_1,x_2,x_3$ are linearly independent because the first three columns and the last column of zeros form a 4x4 augmented matrix where $x_1=x_2=x_3$.